# Where should I use 'use' in php?

Tags: php, namespaces, autoload

I understand that php `use` is most of the time used(no pun intended), to shorten namespaced class names for usage. My question is as follows: I have a project which can possibly use around 300-400 classes. All of these classes are namespaced, and are put in their respective directory, so a registered autoload can include them when they are indeed neccessary, thus preventing the overhead of loading a bunch of files, when they are not necessarily needed.

Now I want to use `use` to shorten some class names, so I may write code faster. My question is as follows:

Where should I put the `use` to shorten these things?

1. Should I put them directly in the script file where the classes needed to be shortened are defined?
2. Could I create a separate file where I define all of my `use` commands?

I would prefer the second option, the only thing I don't know, is that if I do it like that, wouldn't php load all the files that I give as parameter to use?

For example if I do something like this:

```
use My\Class\Path\Class as Class;
use My\Class\Path\Class2 as Class2;
```

will the two files where the definition of the two objects `Class` and `Class2` will be included instantly, or only when I later in the code write something like `new Class()`.

Comment: They will included (autoloader) if the class is created via `new`, not before.

Comment: To your second point. `use` is only working in the current file, not anywhere else.

Comment: Just fyi, `use` can contain a partial path. Example: `use very\long\path\to\my\interfaces as i` then us it `class a implements i\interfacename`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the second point clear, this is content of one file `namespacetest.php`:

```
 namespace x {
    class a {}
 }
 namespace y {
    use x\a;
    class b extends a {}
 }
 namespace {//global namespace
    use y\b as a;
    new a();
 }
```

You can know go and place each namespace block in a seperate file and it works in the same way.

And something about `include`:

Lets say we have one file `inctest.php` with `<?php  $var=123; ?>` in it.

If we inlcude it this way:

```
function yxz(){
   include 'inctest.php';
}
```

we create a local variable in the function called `$var`.

If we do

```
function xyz(){}
include 'inctest.php';
```

we have created a global variable in php called `$var`.

At the lowest level `include` just merges php scripts! If the scripts defines/declares classes/functions there will be just declared/defined. But when in the script that is included is global code (not in a function or so), then it depends heavy on the place you include it, how the included code/script will work. (see examples above)

Answer (score 1):

> 2. Could I create a separate file where I define all of my `use` commands?

You cannot have this this ([docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php)):

> Note: Importing rules are per file basis, meaning included files will
>   NOT inherit the parent file's importing rules.

which clears up your doubts :)

Answer (score 0):

use this way (Example below:) for more clarification visit (http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.faq.php#language.namespaces.faq.innamespace)

```
<?php
namespace foo;
use blah\blah as foo;

$a = new name(); // instantiates "foo\name" class
foo::name(); // calls static method "name" in class "blah\blah"
?>
```